# catch queues overﬂow exceptions when they occur

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

```
void IntQueue::enqueue(int num)
    {
        if (isFull())
            throw std::runtime_error("The queue is full");
        else
        {
            // Calculate the new rear position
            rear = (rear + 1) % queueSize;
            // Insert new item
            queueArray[rear] = num;
            // Update item count
            numItems++;
        }
    }
```

after I throw this exception how can I rewrite the main program so that it catches overﬂow exceptions when they occur. The exception handler for queue overﬂow should print an appropriate error message and then terminate the program. here is the main program

```
int main()
{
    IntQueue iQueue(5);

    cout << "Enqueuing 5 items...\n";
    // Enqueue 5 items.
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        iQueue.enqueue(x);

    // Attempt to enqueue a 6th item.
    cout << "Now attempting to enqueue again...\n";
    iQueue.enqueue(5);
  
  // Deqeue and retrieve all items in the queue
    cout << "The values in the queue were:\n";
    while (!iQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        int value;
        iQueue.dequeue(value);
        cout << value << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`try`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) (no pun intended)?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the part that can throw with [`try-block`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch).

For example,

```cpp
    try
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            iQueue.enqueue(x);

        // Attempt to enqueue a 6th item.
        cout << "Now attempting to enqueue again...\n";
        iQueue.enqueue(5);
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl; // Print error message
        exit(1); // Terminate with non-zero exit code
    }
```